# isapi redirector and IIS 7.5

Tags: isapi

I have hit a problem trying to install the 64 bit ISAPI redirector on to a Windows 2008 Server running ISS 7.5.

Everything seems to be set-up correctly in ISS but I get this error in the ISAPI log file.

I have copied the path in the error message and pasted it into a Windows Explorer address bar and it displays the correct file.

**From the isapi log file**

```
[Thu Mar 29 00:58:25.848 2012] [2360:1132] [info] init_jk::jk_isapi_plugin.c (2653): Starting Jakarta/ISAPI/isapi_redirector/1.2.33
[Thu Mar 29 00:58:25.848 2012] [2360:1132] [debug] init_jk::jk_isapi_plugin.c (2671): Detected IIS version 7.5
[Thu Mar 29 00:58:25.848 2012] [2360:1132] [debug] init_jk::jk_isapi_plugin.c (2676): Using registry.
[Thu Mar 29 00:58:25.848 2012] [2360:1132] [debug] init_jk::jk_isapi_plugin.c (2679): Using log file D:\IIS\IIS7_ISAPI\ISAPI\logs\isapi_redirect.log.
[Thu Mar 29 00:58:25.848 2012] [2360:1132] [debug] init_jk::jk_isapi_plugin.c (2680): Using log level 1.
[Thu Mar 29 00:58:25.848 2012] [2360:1132] [debug] init_jk::jk_isapi_plugin.c (2681): Using log rotation time 0 seconds.
[Thu Mar 29 00:58:25.848 2012] [2360:1132] [debug] init_jk::jk_isapi_plugin.c (2682): Using log file size 0 bytes.
[Thu Mar 29 00:58:25.864 2012] [2360:1132] [debug] init_jk::jk_isapi_plugin.c (2684): Using extension uri /jakarta/isapi_redirect.dll.
[Thu Mar 29 00:58:25.864 2012] [2360:1132] [debug] init_jk::jk_isapi_plugin.c (2685): Using worker file D:\IIS\IIS7_ISAPI\ISAPI\conf\workers.properties.minimal.
[Thu Mar 29 00:58:25.864 2012] [2360:1132] [debug] init_jk::jk_isapi_plugin.c (2686): **Using worker mount file D:\IIS\IIS7_ISAPI\ISAPI\conf\uriworkermap.properties.**
[Thu Mar 29 00:58:25.864 2012] [2360:1132] [debug] init_jk::jk_isapi_plugin.c (2688): Using rewrite rule file .
[Thu Mar 29 00:58:25.864 2012] [2360:1132] [debug] init_jk::jk_isapi_plugin.c (2690): Using uri select 3.
[Thu Mar 29 00:58:25.864 2012] [2360:1132] [debug] init_jk::jk_isapi_plugin.c (2691): Using no chunked encoding.
[Thu Mar 29 00:58:25.864 2012] [2360:1132] [debug] init_jk::jk_isapi_plugin.c (2693): Using notification event SF_NOTIFY_AUTH_COMPLETE (0x04000000)
[Thu Mar 29 00:58:25.864 2012] [2360:1132] [debug] init_jk::jk_isapi_plugin.c (2703): Using uri header TOMCATURI0000000180000000:.
[Thu Mar 29 00:58:25.864 2012] [2360:1132] [debug] init_jk::jk_isapi_plugin.c (2704): Using query header TOMCATQUERY0000000180000000:.
[Thu Mar 29 00:58:25.864 2012] [2360:1132] [debug] init_jk::jk_isapi_plugin.c (2705): Using worker header TOMCATWORKER0000000180000000:.
[Thu Mar 29 00:58:25.864 2012] [2360:1132] [debug] init_jk::jk_isapi_plugin.c (2706): Using worker index TOMCATWORKERIDX0000000180000000:.
[Thu Mar 29 00:58:25.864 2012] [2360:1132] [debug] init_jk::jk_isapi_plugin.c (2707): Using translate header TOMCATTRANSLATE0000000180000000:.
[Thu Mar 29 00:58:25.864 2012] [2360:1132] [debug] init_jk::jk_isapi_plugin.c (2708): Using a default of 250 connections per pool.
[Thu Mar 29 00:58:25.864 2012] [2360:1132] **[error] uri_worker_map_load::jk_uri_worker_map.c (1229): Failed to load uri_worker_map file D:\IIS\IIS7_ISAPI\ISAPI\conf\uriworkermap.properties (errno=2, err=No such file or directory).
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check the security section in the properties of the file.
Add the user which is running the application pool for your site, to have read permissions for this file. By default this would be the application pool identity, for which the user name is 'IIS APPPOOL{app pool name}'.